# Google Dataflow template BigQuery Table Reference Exception

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to stream data from PubSub to BigQuery but getting this error in the log of Dataflow.

Error message from worker: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Table reference is not in [project_id]:[dataset_id].[table_id] format: round-legacy-334414:users.user_list

I tried the below BigQuery output table locations and still got the above error.

```
round-legacy-334414:users.user_list
[round-legacy-334414]:[users].[user_list]
```

Comment: The first format is correct (without the square brackets). Can you make sure that the project_id, dataset_id, and table_id are all correct? Also that you have permissions to write to that table?

Comment: @Cubez The project_id, dataset_id, and table_id are all correct. The issue was with permission. After giving the necessary permission it worked. Thanks

Comment: Hi, I'm facing the same issue. What permissions did you give? I have given the service account roles/dataflow.worker and roles/bigquery.dataEditor already

Answer (score 0):

Yes, IAM permission issue.

I got a similar error another Dataflow job, given bigquery admin role and tried again, the job is successful.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).